# How would I use data to find specific humidity and mixing ratio?

Tags: meteorology, temperature, humidity

I keep reviewing this table to compare and contrast my results:

[image: chart of humidity vs temperature]

The parcel of air is at 35°C and a relative humidity of 43%.

I used [this online calculator](https://www.lenntech.com/calculators/humidity/relative-humidity.htm) and it stated that with these two factors it would be 16.01 g/kg. Is this correct? What is the formula for this answer?

If that is right how would one use that information in order to find the specific humidity? If the atmospheric pressure is at 1000 mb, what would its mixing ratio be?

Comment: Isn't this just the Clausius-Clapeyron equation for water? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation

Answer (score 3):

The online calculator is giving you the specific humidity, which at a relative humidity of 43% is 43% of the saturation specific humidity at that temperature.

Reading from the chart, a rough estimate for the saturation specific humidity is ~37.5 g/kg at 35°C. 43% of this is 16.1 g/kg, which is close to the value given by the calculator.